# How to specialise class template contingent on definition of T::key_type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a class template `ID`, which currently uses an object's address as its identifier.

I would like to have a specialisation of this class template so that if `T` has a `key_type` defined, I will call `get_key()` on the object and use that, instead, as the identifier.  Of course, I will also store that value, so there will be a high degree of overlap with the original implementation.

*What's the best way to achieve this, while maximizing code reuse?*

In the code below, I would like `ID<Bar>` to automagically use `std::string` in its guts rather than `Bar const*`.

I tried looking into SFINAE, as a way of switching on whether or not `T::key_type` is defined, but I could only find examples for function templates.

**CODE**

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
class ID
{
private:
    T const* m_id;
public:
    ID( T const& t ) :
        m_id( &t )
    { }
    ID( ID const& rhs ) :
        m_id( rhs.m_id )
    { }
    ~ID() { }
    ID& operator=( ID const& rhs )
    {
        if ( &rhs!=this )
            m_id = rhs.m_id;
        return *this;
    }
public:
    bool operator==( ID const& rhs ) const { return m_id==rhs.m_id; }
    bool operator!=( ID const& rhs ) const { return !(*this==rhs);  }
    bool operator<( ID const& rhs ) const  { return m_id<rhs.m_id;  }
    bool operator<=( ID const& rhs ) const { return m_id<=rhs.m_id; }
    bool operator>( ID const& rhs ) const  { return m_id>rhs.m_id;  }
    bool operator>=( ID const& rhs ) const { return m_id>=rhs.m_id; }
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Foo { };
struct Bar { 
    using key_type = std::string;

    std::string  m_key;
    Bar( std::string const& key ) : m_key( key ) { }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Foo f,g;

    ID<Foo> id_f( f ), id_g( g );
    assert( id_f!=id_g );

    std::set<ID<Foo>>  s;
    s.insert( f );
    s.insert( g );

    assert( s.size()==2u );

    Bar h( "abc" ), i( "abc" );
    std::set<ID<Bar>>  s2;
    s2.insert( h );
    s2.insert( i );
    assert( s2.size()==1u );
}
```

I was able to code up a solution based on [Seth Carnegie's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14722770/975129).

**SOLUTION**

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
struct void_ {
    using type = void;
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct ptr_or_key_type {
    using type = T const*;               // our default key_type : ptr
    static type get_key( T const& t ) { return &t; }
};

template<typename T>
struct ptr_or_key_type<T, typename void_<typename T::key_type>::type> {
    using type = typename T::key_type;   // the specialised key_type
    static type get_key( T const& t ) { return t.get_key(); }
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename T>
class ID
{
private:
  typename ptr_or_key_type<T>::type m_id;

public:
    ID( T const& t ) :
        m_id( ptr_or_key_type<T>::get_key( t ))
    { }
    ID( ID const& rhs ) :
        m_id( rhs.m_id )
    { }
    ~ID() { }
    ID& operator=( ID const& rhs )
    {
        if ( &rhs!=this )
            m_id = rhs.m_id;
        return *this;
    }
public:
    bool operator==( ID const& rhs ) const { return m_id==rhs.m_id; }
    bool operator!=( ID const& rhs ) const { return !(*this==rhs);  }
    bool operator<( ID const& rhs ) const  { return m_id<rhs.m_id;  }
    bool operator<=( ID const& rhs ) const { return m_id<=rhs.m_id; }
    bool operator>( ID const& rhs ) const  { return m_id>rhs.m_id;  }
    bool operator>=( ID const& rhs ) const { return m_id>=rhs.m_id; }
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Foo { };
struct Bar { 
    using key_type = std::string;

    std::string  m_key;
    Bar( std::string const& key ) : m_key( key ) { }
    std::string const& get_key() const { return m_key; }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Foo f,g;

    ID<Foo> id_f( f ), id_g( g );
    assert( id_f!=id_g );

    std::set<ID<Foo>>  s;
    s.insert( f );
    s.insert( g );

    assert( s.size()==2u );

    Bar h( "abc" ), i( "abc" );
    std::set<ID<Bar>>  s2;
    s2.insert( h );
    s2.insert( i );
    assert( s2.size()==1u );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SFINAE a small combo of traits classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct void_ {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct key_type_or_id {
     using type = T const*; // Our default key_type
};

template<typename T>
struct key_type_or_id<T, typename void_<typename T::key_type>::type> {
    using type = typename T::key_type; // The specialised key_type
};

...

template<typename T>
class ID
{
private:
    typename key_type_or_id<T>::type m_id;

...
```

Comment: the use of void_<> as a tag for specialisation is mind-blowing: it's going to take me a while to get my head around that one

Comment: @kfmfe04 the reason it works is that you're creating a general template with a second template param that defaults to `void`, and then (if `T` has a member `key_type`) you're **specialising for the general case**. It's weird, but because the default `void` is used (for which you specialised) the compiler chooses the more specialised type and you don't get a double-definition error. See http://liveworkspace.org/code/4ljAdU$8 for a blunt example.

Comment: +1 ty for that great example - it makes more sense now (I was looking at it backwards).  The interesting thing is, `std::cout << S<double,int>::b;` dumps `20` as I expect, but `std::cout << S<double,void>::b;` fails to compile!

Comment: @kfmfe04 well, it's just that `S<T, void>` where `T` is _any_ type will get you the specialisation that doesn't have `b` defined as a static member (and leaving out a second type always gets you the specialisation too, since `<T>` expands to `<T, void>`).

Comment: ack - of course: (the compiler will match the specialisation first)!  Mind getting mushy - gonna take a break.